# Can't scroll down in youtube (My code can run some website, but not with Youtube) using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# execute url
url = "https://www.youtube.com/user/xuanvinh1612/community"
driver_path = ('F:/chromedriver.exe')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
browser.get(url)

# Auto scroll and auto click with text:'Read more'
read_mores2 = browser.find_elements_by_link_text('Read more')
for read_mores2 in read_mores2:
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", read_mores2)
    browser.execute_script("$(arguments[0]).click();", read_mores2)
    # Scroll down stop when all post was showed
    read_mores2 = browser.find_elements_by_link_text('Read more')
```

With a same code, my code can run some website(2-3 another website). But when i re-use code for auto scroll down and auto click on Youtube/community, it not working. I dont know how it not work. I need help, please.

Comment: You code is very confusion as your are using read_mores2 for everything!
```read_mores2 = ...``` in your for loop as not effect as you cannot reassign the value during iteration. Can you try by change from for loop, to a while loop. Also ```browser.find_elements_by_link_text('Read more')``` does not exist on your page. Which mean the loop will never be executed.

Comment: in another website, my code is working, youtube is not. Can you tell me why text:'Read more' does not exist on my page? Because my page have a text 'Read more'

Comment: I am not familiar with link_text, but I tried it and it returned an empty list. You can try using the class_name: more-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:
It will first load all the pages, then click on all Read More.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
# execute url
url = "https://www.youtube.com/user/xuanvinh1612/community"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

# Auto scroll and auto click with text:'Read more'
previous_count = 0
page_sections = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.style-scope.ytd-item-section-renderer')
current_count = len(page_sections)
print("Scrolling to enable all the pages")
while previous_count != current_count:
    try:
        previous_count = current_count
        browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", page_sections[-1])
        print("Number of total Elements found: {}".format(len(page_sections)))
    finally:
        # As the page load the newer elements, you need to implement logic here to wait until the loading spinner at the
        # button becomes invisible (not attached to the DOM)
        time.sleep(2)  # WorkAround as you need to implement the above logic here
        page_sections = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.style-scope.ytd-item-section-renderer')
        current_count = len(page_sections)

print("Clicking on all Read More")
for read_more in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.more-button'):
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", read_more)
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", read_more)
```

Comment: why you remove '$' in line `arguments[0].click();`? In another website, I must using `$arguments[0].click();` to work. But in youtube, system call error : `Message: javascript error: $ is not defined`. Can you tell me why?, thanks for help

Comment: $ is a variable that is defined either by using var or depending of the framework being used by dev. For example, $ would be short for jQuery().